# Empirical Rule Precision?

Tags: statistics

Apologies if this has been asked before.

I was working on my Math Stats homework and came across this interesting "contradiction". The question specifically I have specifically pertains to 4.76 below.

4.75) A soft-drink machine can be regulated so that it discharges an average of μ ounces per cup. If the ounces of fill are normally distributed with standard deviation 0.3 ounce, give the setting for μ so that 8-ounce cups will overflow only 1% of the time.

**4.76) The machine described in Exercise 4.75 has standard deviation σ that can be fixed at certain levels by carefully adjusting the machine. What is the largest value of σ that will allow the actual amount dispensed to fall within 1 ounce of the mean with probability at least .95?**

Using the empirical rule, my first instinct was to set up the equation and solve as follows;
$$7.3 + 2σ = 8.3$$
$$σ = \frac{8.3 - 7.3}{2}$$
$$σ = 0.5$$

However, this was wrong. The other way that occurred to me was to find the actual z-score associated to the area described in the problem. According to the z-table, the number of standards deviations from the mean associated to an area of 95% is ±1.96. So, resetting the equation gave the following;

$$7.3 + 1.96σ = 8.3$$
$$σ = \frac{8.3 - 7.3}{1.96}$$
$$σ = 0.5102$$

And this was correct! I'm assuming this is because the empirical rule is only an approximation, not exact, but this came as a surprise to me since in all my statistics courses, that fact has never been mentioned. I'd just like to get some confirmation for that before I start going off of that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The empirical rule (aka 68-95-99.7% rule) is just a rounded approximation.  The exact probabilities (and rounding to the nearest IEEE `double`) for the normal distribution are:

- $P(|z| < 1) = \operatorname{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) \approx 0.6826894921370859$
- $P(|z| < 2) = \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{2}) \approx 0.9544997361036416$
- $P(|z| < 3) = \operatorname{erf}(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}) \approx 0.9973002039367398$

Where `erf` denotes [the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

So, using a whole 2 standard deviations actually gives you an (approximately) 95.45% confidence interval.  Most of the time, that extra 0.45% probability isn't a big deal, but if you want a hyper-precise 95% confidence interval, you have to use $z = \sqrt{2}\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(0.95) \approx 1.9599639845400543$.